# Technique to test antibiotic resistance in a bacteria in presence of another compound

Tags: biochemistry, microbiology, bacteriology, antibiotics

so I have to 'quantitatively' assess a bacterial strain for its antibiotic resistance property (it is a specific antibiotic) in the presence and absence of another compound alongside antibiotic. What technique or protocol can be followed?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might employ a "Disk diffusion test" described in this Wikipedia article.  It could be done with and without the secondary adjuvant compound and be quantified by measurement of the varying diameters of the resulting zones of bacterial inhibition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_diffusion_test

Comment: thank you that was very helpful but the page does not describe how to add adjuvants in the equation. I googled for it and still couldn't find a satisfactory answer

Comment: I suppose you would add them to the mueller-hinton when making the plate, a few for each concentration of the other compound you want to test. Then run the disk diffusion as usual.

Comment: Eliane B - obviously.  The question involves the addition of a potential adjuvant (other compound).  It's addition can be determined by the experiment.